# in Jupyter, pip reports different version of python module than is imported

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have upgraded a module as follows

```
!pip install py2neo==3.1.2 --user --upgrade
```

pip confirms that the right version is installed. 
That is, running this:

```
!pip show py2neo
```

gives this:

```
Name: py2neo
Version: 3.1.2
Summary: Python client library and toolkit for Neo4j
Home-page: http://py2neo.org/
Author: Nigel Small <nigel@py2neo.org>
Author-email: nigel@py2neo.org
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: c:\users\db15237\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: neo4j-doc-manager
```

But if I import the module, it imports an older version. This code:

```
import py2neo
print(py2neo.__version__)
```

returns `2.0.8`

How do I import version 3.1.2, which pip says is installed?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv or something of the kind? What is the value of `sys.path`?

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge. sys.path gives: `['', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\db15237\\.ipython']`

Comment: `c:\users\db15237\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages` is not even in your `sys.path` when you call python. This means you have two installations of python, the one installed with conda (which pops up first in `PATH`) and the one somewhere in `c:\users\db15237\appdata\roaming\python` which your default `pip` serves. Organize the `PATH` so `pip` from `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` is found before the one from `c:\users\db15237\appdata\roaming\python`.

Comment: very silly of me not to notice that - I've been staring at various problems too long and I've lost perspective. time for a break. Thanks v much